# How to update google play services m2repository?

Tags: android, google-play-services

My `playServices` `m2repository` version is 58 (11.0.4).
The location is:

```
my_android_sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms
```

Android sdkmanager GUI shows version 58, no update available.

This command

```
./tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
```

doesn't show any updates for `m2repository` either.

Is there any way to get the latest `aar`-files for `playservices`?

**Solution**:

I found the packages here:

[play-services-ads-11.6.0](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/11.6.0/play-services-ads-11.6.0.aar)

[play-services-location-11.6.0](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/11.6.0/play-services-location-11.6.0.aar)

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on what's inside the m2repository folder of your SDK but on the libraries version you set on your application. AARs are automatically downloaded when you add a dependency like those ones:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$LAST_LIB_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:$LAST_LIB_VERSION"
    //read below to know $LAST_LIB_VERSION values
    ....
}
//the google play services plugin, applied at the end of the build.gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

First of all you should have a project `build.gradle` similar to this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$LATEST_AGP_VERSION"
        //as the time of writing $LATEST_AGP_VERSION is 3.0.1

        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$GPS_VERSION"
        //read below for $GPS_VERSION values
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> 1. *$GPS_VERSION* valid values are inside [this page](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services#release)
> 2. *$LAST_LIB_VERSION* valid values:
>
>    - If you are **NOT** using Firebase functionalities, follow the dependencies version of [this
>        page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases), and the dependencies available are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)
>    - If you are using Firebase functionalities, follow the dependencies version of [this
>        page](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), and the dependencies available are listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries)

That's all.